# BeautifulSoup slow on Django view but normal locally

Tags: python, django, performance, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping using BeautifulSoup in a Django view to get some img src and show them on my page. My problem is: when I execute the code in Jupyter Notebook it takes less than one second to do this task but when I do it in my django view it takes more or less 10 seconds (depends on the query).

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
import time
import json


def get_soup(url,header):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)),'html.parser')

def get_images(query):
    start_time = time.time()
    url="https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
    header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"
    }
    soup = get_soup(url,header)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    start_time = time.time()
    ActualImages=[]# contains the link for Large original images, type of  image
    for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):
        link =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]
        ActualImages.append(link)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    dic = {'images': ActualImages[:10]}
    return dic

get_images('thunder')
```

The problem is while running the 'get_soap()' function. Is this normal? Any ideia of to make it faster?

Comment: Does your django server operate locally as well as Jupyter?

Comment: yes, it is! I'm running django with 'manage.py runserver'

Comment: Maybe you should post your view code as well

Comment: These two functions are in my views.py, the timer does not count the time for the whole process only the time needed for the "get_soup" function.